# How to add three arrays in stack java

Tags: data-structures, java

I am trying to add three arrays so when entering in the stack when array 1 is full move to the next array and get size and so on I made the following code but not working
(it may be very long but that what I can do for my bad experience in java )

```
private int itop1,itop2,itop3;         //top of the array list
int ArraSize=3;     // MAx size of the array
int [] Array1,Array2,Array3;        //first array


public LinkedSt (){

    itop1=-1;
    itop2=-1;
    itop3=-1;
    Array1=new int [ArraSize];
    //head.next=tail.next=null;
    Array2=new int [ArraSize];
    Array3=new int [ArraSize];
    } 
public void push1 (int el){

    if (isStackFull2()&&isStackFull1()){
        System.out.println("Fuckin FUll");}

    if (itop2<Array2.length){
    addToHead(el);
    itop2=itop2+1;
    Array1[itop2]=el;
}
    if (itop1<Array1.length){
    addToHead(el);
    itop1=itop1+1;
    Array1[itop1]=el;
    }


public class LinkedSt extends SingleLinkList {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LinkedSt myLinkedSt= new LinkedSt();
    System.out.println("Is the linked stack empty??"+myLinkedSt.isEmpty());
    System.out.println("Is the linked stack Full??"+myLinkedSt.isStackFull1());
    System.out.println("Size"+myLinkedSt.size());
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    System.out.println("Size"+myLinkedSt.size());
    System.out.println("after pushing 10");
    System.out.println("Is the linked stack empty??"+myLinkedSt.isEmpty());
    System.out.println("Is the linked stack Full??"+myLinkedSt.isStackFull1());
    System.out.println("stack full and pushing 10");
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    System.out.println("Size"+myLinkedSt.size());
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    System.out.println("Size"+myLinkedSt.size());
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    System.out.println("Size"+myLinkedSt.size());
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    System.out.println("Size"+myLinkedSt.size());
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    System.out.println("Size"+myLinkedSt.size());
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    myLinkedSt.push1(10);
    myLinkedSt.printList();
}
```

Comment: To solve this question, you do not need to create a Three Arrays. First you can just define an array that is big enough let say of size 5,000. Secondly according to the definition of an array, if the array is full then you need to create another array that is 2 X or 4 X your current one then moving everything from the current array to the new one that is 2 X, if the current is full. Another option to avoid this moving of elements, is to use an Arraylist. An Arraylist will automatically resize on its own if it is full.

Answer (score 0):

There is easier ways to implements cyclic arrays.

Here is a quick attempts using a two-dimension array.

```
public class CyclicArray{

    private static final int NB_ARRAYS = 3; //The number of array
    private static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 5; //The length of each array
    private int[][] arrays = new int[NB_ARRAYS][];
    private int currentArray = -1, 
                currentIndex = ARRAY_SIZE; //Those value are set to force the first cycle that will create the first array

    public static void main(String[] args){
        CyclicArray main = new CyclicArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
            main.add(i);
        }

        for(int[] array : main.arrays)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public void add(int i){
        if(currentIndex >= ARRAY_SIZE){ //Change of array
            currentIndex = 0; 
            currentArray = ++currentArray % NB_ARRAYS; //Using % to return at the beginning

            if(arrays[currentArray] == null){ //Create if it doesn't exist (could be done at the beginning instead)
                arrays[currentArray] = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
            }
        }

        arrays[currentArray][currentIndex++] = i; //incrementing the currentIndex after use
    }
}
```

This will add a value in the next cell of the current array. When it reach the end, this will use the next array. Once you reach the end, reuse the first array (overriding the values)

## Output

The small example present will output this :

> [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>
> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>
> [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

Comment: To stop when everything is full, you just need to remove the % and add some check (to prevent exceptions)